# Passing arguments in ode45

Tags: matlab, ode, matlab-deployment, differential-equations

I want to pass a simple argument in my `ode45` function. My function is as follows:

```
function dxdt = state( t,x,vgth,vgval)
p=1;
k=10^0.7;
window1=1-((2*x)-1).^(2*p);
dxdt=k*(vgval-vgth+1.2)*window1;  
end
```

The main script is:

```
clear all
step=0.01;
t = 0:step:10;
f=2*0.157;
vg = 5*sin(2*f*t);
x0=0.01;
vgth=1.9;
[t,x] = ode45(@(t,x) state1 (t,x,vgth,vg(t)), t, x0);
plot(t,x)
```

Here When I exclude the parameter `vg(t)`  in the argument passing, the whole works just fine. But It doesn't work with `vg(t)` in the argument.

Comment: Can't you pass it also as anonymous function parameter inside the anonymous function? 
`ode45(@(t,x) state1(t,x,@(u) 5*sin(2*f*u), vgth) , ... )`?

Or simply as `ode45(@(t,x) state1(t,x,vg(t), vgth) , ... )` with a pre-defined function `vg`.

Comment: @LutzL...I used the simple way which you described . Like I used the following code in my script. `[t,x] = ode45(@(t,x) state1 (t,x,vgth,vg(t)), t, x0);` and my main function as `function dxdt = state( t,x,vgth,vg(t))`..But it gives me same error

Comment: No, the parameter that `state` gets is just a number,  so use `function dxdt = state( t,x,vgth,vgval)` where `vgval` (or any other name) is understood to contain the value of `vg(t)` in the call from `ode45`.

Comment: @LutzL...I did this way now `function dxdt = state( t,x,vgth,vgval)`and my script is now `[t,x] = ode45(@(t,x) state1 (t,x,vgth,vg(t)), t, x0);`..Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. It should work that way.

Comment: @LutzL..I have edited my code according to your suggestions and included that edited code in my question ( Question edited ) . Can you kindly review it now to help me figure out.

Comment: It does not work because `vg` is not a function. Change to `vg = @(t) 5*sin(2*f*t);` to make a function out of it.

Comment: @LutzL...Thanks alot..that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assembling the comments to an answer:

```
function dxdt = state( t,x,vgth,vgval)
    p=1;
    k=10^0.7;
    window1=1-((2*x)-1).^(2*p);
    dxdt=k*(vgval-vgth+1.2)*window1;  
end

function vgval = vg(t)
    f=2*0.157;
    vgval = 5*sin(2*f*t);  
end 

step=0.01;
t = 0:step:10;
x0=0.01;
vgth=1.9;
[t,x] = ode45(@(t,x) state(t,x,vgth,vg(t)), t, x0);
```

This should hopefully work as intended.

Comment: I have edited my code according to your suggestions and included that edited code in my question ( Question edited ) . Can you kindly review it now to help me figure out.

Comment: the `vg(t)` should be generated right after `t` vector in the main script and then passed to the main function in an argument. Thanks for your kind help

Comment: You do not know at which points `ode45` will evaluate the (reduced) `state` function resp. the anonymous ODE function. The list `t` in the argument only determines the sampling points for the output, not the internal steps. Thus it makes no sense to apply `vg` to the vector/list `t`.